# javascript function pointer and "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

Using jsPlumb to bind, I'm passing a method as a variable to be used as a callback. When its called, the "this" is not the object the method is a member of. How do I go about getting access to the method's object instance so I can get access to it variables and other member functions?

I have no control over the callback call method, its a separate library. All I do is call the binding from my object init method. I would have expected `this` inside my `_connection` method to have been its object.

```
jsPlumb.bind('connection', this._connection);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `this` for any `function` is [determined when it's called](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). The `function` really has no other ties to the "*object*" than whether or not it was called as `object.method()` or `method.call(object)`.

So, to pass a `function` with a fixed `this` value, it'll need to be [bound](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Bound_functions):

```
jsPlumb.bind('connection', this._connection.bind(this));
```

jQuery also includes a wrapper and compatibility fill for this with [`jQuery.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
jsPlumb.bind('connection', $.proxy(this._connection, this));
```

Comment: But, the first argument to `.bind()` is supposed to be the object itself that you want the `this` pointer to be, not a string `'connection'` like you and the OP have.  I don't see how you're solving anything with your code.

Comment: @jfriend00 I assumed that `jsPlumb.bind()` was for an event handler rather than function context, with `'connection'` being the event name.

Answer (score 1):

A more complicated version if you don't want to use Function.prototype.bind (because it's not supported in older browsers) and you don't want to use jquery is:

```
jsPlumb.bind('connection', (function(me){
  return function(){
    me._connection();// no need for call, apply or bind
  }
})(this));
```

Losing `this` when passing object methods is a common problem, here is the problem and it's solution re produced in script:

```
var ps={//publish subscribe
  messages:{},
  add:function(m,fn){
    if(!this.messages[m]){
      this.messages[m]=[];
    }
    this.messages[m].push(fn);
  },
  publish:function(m,data){
    var i = 0;
    var msg=this.messages[m];
    for(i=0;i<msg.length;i++){
      msg[i](data);
    }
  }
}

function test(){
}
test.prototype.logit=function(data){
  console.log(data,this.toString());
};
test.prototype.toString=function(){
  return "This is a test object";
}
// self made bind function
function myBind(me,fn){
  return function(){
    fn.apply(me,arguments);
  }
}
var t=new test();
// pass a closure instead of a function
ps.add("test1",(function(me){
      return function(data){
        me.logit(data);
      }
    })(t)
);
// pass a function
ps.add("test2",t.logit);
// function created with bind
ps.add("test3",t.logit.bind(t));
// passing closure using myBind
ps.add("test4",myBind(t,t.logit));
// next line will log "This is a test object"
ps.publish("test1","Passing a closure instead of the function, this is:");
// next line will log "function (data){console.log(..."
// so `this` is not test but test.logit
ps.publish("test2","Passing a the function, this is:");
// next line will log "This is a test object"
ps.publish("test3","Passing a the function using bind, this is:");
// next line will log "This is a test object"
ps.publish("test4","Passing a closure with myBind, this is:");
```